# Automating excel reporting and graphs - Python xlsxWriter/xlswings or Ruby axlsx/win32ole

Tags: python, ruby, excel, xlsxwriter, axlsx

I want to create a program, which automates excel reporting including various graphs in colours. The program needs to be able to read an excel dataset. Based on this dataset, the program then has to create report pages and graphs and then export to an excel file as well as pdf file.

I have done some research and it seems this is possible using python with pandas - xlsxWriter or xlswings as well as Ruby gems - axlsx or win32ole.

Which is the user-friendlier and easy to learn alternative? What are the advantages and disadvantages? Are there other options I should consider (I would like to avoid VBA - as this is how the reports are currently produced)?

Any responses and comments are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you could use either language. If you end up using Ruby, definitely use [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx), it's super simple (much easier than win32ole).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have VBA that *works* for your project, then translating it to Ruby + WIN32OLE is probably your quickest path to working code. Anything you can do in VBA is doable in Ruby (if you find something you can't do, post here to ask for help).

I prefer working with Excel via OLE since I know the file produced by Excel *will work* anywhere I open it. I haven't used axlsx but I'm sure it's a fine project; I just wouldn't trust that it would produce working Excel files every time.

Comment: Thank you Chuck for your answer. Does this mean that OLE runs the graph in Excel? That's what I want to avoid - because the datasets are too large and the macros take forever to run. I don't want Excel to process the data, I only want the results to be presented in Excel.

Comment: My suggestion was to "port" your existing VBA to Ruby. If the current code takes "forever" to run then Ruby + WIN32OLE won't be any better. However, you could modify your code to run your dataset calculations in Ruby and then use OLE to produce a chart from the results. No reason this can't work.